# How can I track 'Open' statistics on Firebase Messaging campaigns for my Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, firebase, statistics, messaging

I have an app developed in Flutter and I use Firebase Console to send messages to it. The app receives the messages, but it only shows 'Sends' statistics for each campaign.

What should I do to see other data (such as 'Opened' statistics)?